# Javascript: what is a sure way to retrieve data from two XML nodes that have the same tag name?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlnode

Fully functioning example.

The problem: Some `<UNIT>` nodes have several `<NAMES>` child nodes while others have none. How can I retrieve the data from sibling nodes that have the same name tag `<NAMES>` if I don't know their positions in the node tree? Is there a simple way to get their relative position?

For example, how can I retrieve the "California" attributes contained in the `<NAMES>` tags (I only successfully retrieved the first 2 attributes):
`California Republic
The Golden State
California
CA
The Eureka State
Golden West`

Note: The XML nodes are not formatted consistently, and I'm not allowed to alter the XML.

```js
/*retrieve specific XML nodes*/
function testResults() {
const { value } = myInputId;
const foundState = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('STATE')]
.find(possibleMatch => possibleMatch.textContent === value);
const unit = foundState.parentElement;
var u_state = unit.querySelector('STATE') ? unit.querySelector('STATE').textContent: "Not Found";
var u_gdp = unit.querySelector('GDP') ? unit.querySelector('GDP').textContent: "Not Found";
var u_pop = unit.querySelector('POPULATION') ? unit.querySelector('POPULATION').textContent: "Not Found";
var u_code = unit.querySelector('CODE') ? unit.querySelector('CODE').textContent: "Not Found";

/*retrieve alternate names attributes from 1st "NAMES" node*/
var u_name1 = unit.querySelector('NAMES') ? unit.querySelector('NAMES').getAttribute('name'): "Not Found";
var u_other1 = unit.querySelector('NAMES') ? unit.querySelector('NAMES').getAttribute('other'): "Not Found";

/*retrieve alternate names attributes from 2nd "NAMES" node*/
var u_name2 = unit.querySelector('NAMES') ? unit.querySelector('NAMES').getAttribute('name'): "Not Found";
var u_other2 = unit.querySelector('NAMES') ? unit.querySelector('NAMES').getAttribute('other'): "Not Found";

/*retrieve alternate names attributes from 3rd "NAMES" node*/
var u_name3 = unit.querySelector('NAMES') ? unit.querySelector('NAMES').getAttribute('name'): "Not Found";
var u_other3 = unit.querySelector('NAMES') ? unit.querySelector('NAMES').getAttribute('other'): "Not Found";

/*show retrieved XML data*/
document.getElementById("u_state").innerHTML = u_state ;
document.getElementById("u_gdp").innerHTML = u_gdp ;
document.getElementById("u_pop").innerHTML = u_pop;
document.getElementById("u_code").innerHTML = u_code;
document.getElementById("u_name1").innerHTML = u_name1;
document.getElementById("u_other1").innerHTML = u_other1;
document.getElementById("u_name2").innerHTML = u_name2;
document.getElementById("u_other2").innerHTML = u_other2;
document.getElementById("u_name3").innerHTML = u_name3;
document.getElementById("u_other3").innerHTML = u_other3;
}

/*simulate xmlDoc*/
var parser, xmlDoc, x, i;
var text = `<STATE_DATA>
  <UNIT>
    <STATE>California</STATE>
    <GDP>2,500,000,000,000</GDP>
    <POPULATION>39,600,000</POPULATION>
    <NAMES name='California Republic' other='The Golden State' />
    <NAMES name='California' other='CA' />
    <NAMES name='The Eureka State' other='Golden West' />
    <CODE>CA</CODE>
  </UNIT>
  <UNIT>
    <STATE>Texas</STATE>
    <GDP>1,600,000,000,000</GDP>
    <POPULATION>28,300,000</POPULATION>
    <NAMES name='Republic of Texas' other='The Lone Star State' />
    <NAMES name='Texas' other='TX' />
    <CODE>TX</CODE>
  </UNIT>
</STATE_DATA>
`;
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

/*submit input on ENTER*/
var n = document.getElementById("myInputId");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="testResults()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option id="CA">California</option>
<option id="TX">Texas</option>
</datalist>

<!--display XML data here-->
<p>state: <span id="u_state"></span></p>
<p>gdp: <span id="u_gdp"></span></p>
<p>pop: <span id="u_pop"></span></p>
<p>code: <span id="u_code"></span></p>
<p>name1: <span id="u_name1"></span></p>
<p>other1: <span id="u_other1"></span></p>
<p>name2: <span id="u_name2"></span></p>
<p>other2: <span id="u_other2"></span></p>
<p>name3: <span id="u_name3"></span></p>
<p>other3: <span id="u_other3"></span></p>
```

As you can see in the snippet, this is the XML:

```
<STATE_DATA>
  <UNIT>
    <STATE>California</STATE>
    <GDP>2,500,000,000,000</GDP>
    <POPULATION>39,600,000</POPULATION>
    <NAMES name='California Republic' other='The Golden State' />
    <NAMES name='California' other='CA' />
    <NAMES name='The Eureka State' other='Golden West' />
    <CODE>CA</CODE>
  </UNIT>
  <UNIT>
    <STATE>Texas</STATE>
    <GDP>1,600,000,000,000</GDP>
    <POPULATION>28,300,000</POPULATION>
    <NAMES name='Republic of Texas' other='The Lone Star State' />
    <NAMES name='Texas' other='TX' />
    <CODE>TX</CODE>
  </UNIT>
</STATE_DATA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through all `NAMES` that are children of the found `UNIT`. Don't use `querySelector` for that, since `querySelector` will only return the *first* match, not *the next* match; use `querySelectorAll` instead.

```
const [name1, name2, name3] = unit.querySelectorAll('NAMES');
var u_name1 = name1 ? name1.getAttribute('name') : 'Not Found';
var u_other1 = name1 ? name1.getAttribute('other') : 'Not Found';
var u_name2 = name2 ? name2.getAttribute('name') : 'Not Found';
var u_other2 = name2 ? name2.getAttribute('other') : 'Not Found';
var u_name3 = name3 ? name3.getAttribute('name') : 'Not Found';
var u_other3 = name3 ? name3.getAttribute('other') : 'Not Found';
```

```js
/*retrieve specific XML nodes*/
function testResults() {
  const {
    value
  } = myInputId;
  const foundState = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('STATE')]
    .find(possibleMatch => possibleMatch.textContent === value);
  const unit = foundState.parentElement;
  var u_state = unit.querySelector('STATE') ? unit.querySelector('STATE').textContent : "Not Found";
  var u_gdp = unit.querySelector('GDP') ? unit.querySelector('GDP').textContent : "Not Found";
  var u_pop = unit.querySelector('POPULATION') ? unit.querySelector('POPULATION').textContent : "Not Found";
  var u_code = unit.querySelector('CODE') ? unit.querySelector('CODE').textContent : "Not Found";

  const [name1, name2, name3] = unit.querySelectorAll('NAMES');
  var u_name1 = name1 ? name1.getAttribute('name') : 'Not Found';
  var u_other1 = name1 ? name1.getAttribute('other') : 'Not Found';
  var u_name2 = name2 ? name2.getAttribute('name') : 'Not Found';
  var u_other2 = name2 ? name2.getAttribute('other') : 'Not Found';
  var u_name3 = name3 ? name3.getAttribute('name') : 'Not Found';
  var u_other3 = name3 ? name3.getAttribute('other') : 'Not Found';

  /*show retrieved XML data*/
  document.getElementById("u_state").innerHTML = u_state;
  document.getElementById("u_gdp").innerHTML = u_gdp;
  document.getElementById("u_pop").innerHTML = u_pop;
  document.getElementById("u_code").innerHTML = u_code;
  document.getElementById("u_name1").innerHTML = u_name1;
  document.getElementById("u_other1").innerHTML = u_other1;
  document.getElementById("u_name2").innerHTML = u_name2;
  document.getElementById("u_other2").innerHTML = u_other2;
  document.getElementById("u_name3").innerHTML = u_name3;
  document.getElementById("u_other3").innerHTML = u_other3;
}

/*simulate xmlDoc*/
var parser, xmlDoc, x, i;
var text =
  "<STATE_DATA>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>California</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>2,500,000,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>39,600,000</POPULATION>" +
  /*THREE siblings with the same element tag name "NAMES"*/
  "<NAMES name='California Republic' other='The Golden State' />" +
  "<NAMES name='California' other='CA'/>" +
  "<NAMES name='The Eureka State' other='Golden West'/>" +
  "<CODE>CA</CODE>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "<UNIT>" +
  "<STATE>Texas</STATE>" +
  "<GDP>1,600,000,000,000</GDP>" +
  "<POPULATION>28,300,000</POPULATION>" +
  /*TWO siblings with the same element tag name "NAMES"*/
  "<NAMES name='Republic of Texas' other='The Lone Star State' />" +
  "<NAMES name='Texas' other='TX'/>" +
  "<CODE>TX</CODE>" +
  "</UNIT>" +
  "</STATE_DATA>";
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

/*submit input on ENTER*/
var n = document.getElementById("myInputId");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="testResults()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
<option id="CA">California</option>
<option id="TX">Texas</option>
</datalist>

<!--display XML data here-->
<p>state: <span id="u_state"></span></p>
<p>gdp: <span id="u_gdp"></span></p>
<p>pop: <span id="u_pop"></span></p>
<p>code: <span id="u_code"></span></p>
<p>name1: <span id="u_name1"></span></p>
<p>other1: <span id="u_other1"></span></p>
<p>name2: <span id="u_name2"></span></p>
<p>other2: <span id="u_other2"></span></p>
<p>name3: <span id="u_name3"></span></p>
<p>other3: <span id="u_other3"></span></p>
```

But it would probably be better to use an array instead of variables with hardcoded index names, if you're allowed to do that.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I'll look into arrays. Why would that be better? More efficient?

Comment: It's not more efficient, it's just more readable. If you have an unknown number of items in an array-like object (such as a `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll`), it would just make a lot more sense to iterate through it like an array than to pre-define every attribute for every index.